# Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 Wifi/Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10, ethernet, .desktop

I've searched and haven't been able to find a solution to this. On a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 64b. There doesn't appear to be a way to turn off Wifi to toggle between a wired connection and a wireless one. I *can* disable Wifi, but I am not able to find a way to switch to a wired connection instead. There's no error I've seen to help.

Is there an app I can install to allow for me to switch between the two methods or something else I can do to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Can't you simply uncheck 'Enable Wi-Fi'?  https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2014/07/ubuntu-networkmanager-menu-100360176-large.png

Comment: My version of your screenshot is about half as long as yours. Maybe I need to do more manually during installation to set it properly? I'm not entirely sure. Ubuntu has changed drastically since I used it four or five years ago and I seem to be missing something important.

Comment: Does it look like this? http://i63.tinypic.com/16a45jn.png

Comment: It's an identical panel. My Wifi name is different, as is user, but that can't possibly be an issue. But short answer: yes.

Comment: When you click the Wifi name, does the option to Turn Off appear?

Comment: It does, yes. I think I'm about to run into another problem, though. I have a Mikrotik external wifi that's so poorly documented it doesn't actually say how to turn it off. That's what I'm trying to connect to via the wired connection.

Comment: Er, on, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Only real way to default to a Wired connection is to cut on Airplane mode, and then connect the wired connection. I do this all the time, because my wifi in my house could be a lot FASTER!

Comment: Cool I'll give that a try. There's probably a script I can setup to do it but I'd just prefer to have like a little minipanel near the wifi thing where you can just see available networks, status of ethernet, status of wifi, status of vpn.